# Entity Framework 'Where Or' for multiple user specified IDs

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

The user is able to enter a comma separated list of IDs in a searchbox. This then needs to converted to the following SQL:

```
...
WHERE table.idCol = id1 OR table.idCol = id2 OR table.idCol = id3 ...
```

Given a string array what EF code do I need to write to produce this? The following doesn't work as it produces ANDs instead

```
foreach (string idStr in idString.Split(','))
{
    int id = int.Parse(idStr);
    query = query.Where(t => t.idCol == id);
}
```

Comment: ... WHERE table.idCol IN (id1, id2 etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just use `Contains`, it will be translated as `IN` clause :

```
var idList = idString.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();

var query = table.Where(x => idList.Contains(x.idCol));
```